# What is a correct understanding about iOS provisioning

Tags: ios, ios-provisioning

Hello. I have a problem about mobile provisioning.

My understand is below.

Apps built with provisioning profile for AppStore are only for AppStore review request.
It never installed without AppStore.

However, I could install these apps into my Adhoc device via PC, iTunes and cable connection.

I'm wondering why it was success?
Is my understanding wrong?
If it is wrong. What is correct understand about AppStore mobile provisioning?

Comment: This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: This *might* fall under the "software tools commonly used by programmers" proviso, as it shows the users's confusion with provisioning, which is a requisite part of application development and release for iOS with Xcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read Apple's [App Distribution Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html). It gives more context about what provisioning is used for, that may answer your question.

Basically, your understanding is incorrect. With an Apple developer account, and basic provisioning setup (i.e. you are able to write, compile, and deploy apps onto iOS devices you've registered in the Apple Dev Center), you can deploy apps in any way you find easiest -- Xcode to device, via TestFlight, manual load via iTunes, etcetera -- to the devices that you've registered. The basic ADC account (non-enterprise) can only register 100 devices, and signed applications will also eventually expire.

When you get (i.e. pay for) an ADC account, you're basically paying for the privilege to be able to sign and deploy apps onto a limited number of devices for a limited time. When you eventually release your app to the App Store, the provisioning used is slightly different (again, read the guide above), and the apps do not expire readily and are more widely deployable via the App Store.